# Python function that returns independent value based off list input

Tags: python

I have the below JSON response, I want to write a function that:

1. runs through the response looking for a match of 'risk-level' = [medium OR high]
2. if match found returns the corresponding alert-id in a list / array format (I think we should use .append here)
3. if no match is found, exit the program (I'm pretty sure it would "exit()" here)

I have managed to get it to match / find one input and bring back that response, I'm just struggling with feeding it a list with an "OR" logic to bring back an independent result.

```
[
{'event-num': 5520, 'alert-id': '6e310403-ca53-32ut-aec6-16ffc648f7b7', 'risk-level': 'very-low'},  
{'event-num': 5521, 'alert-id': '0a6b15b7-3db3-2x7t-b4ab-b023cfb85eaf', 'risk-level': 'low'},
{'event-num': 5523, 'alert-id': '6e310403-3db3-4b5f-cehd-16ffc648f7b7', 'risk-level': 'medium'},
{'event-num': 5523, 'alert-id': '0a6b15b7-6ty5-4b5f-cehd-b023cfb85eaf', 'risk-level': 'high'}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.append()` as you mentioned, or, you could do this in a quick list comprehension.

Let's say your list is called `events`.

```py
risky_events = [event['alert-id'] 
                for event in events 
                if event['risk-level'] in {'medium','high'}]
```

The above code simply creates a list of matching risk levels. How would you use the snippet above to implement your `exit()` requirement? You would need to check if the list created above was empty. Give it a try.

What went wrong in the approach you took? Did you try using `.append()` yourself? Look up the Python docs section on lists to understand how append works, and give that approach a try.

Comment: This worked thank you very much! i guess my python beginner course didnt cover these yet (list comprehension). i was trying to do it through a "for" function, where it would find matches of the specific risk-level and do an "incident.get('alert-id' , " ")" to get the alert-id, but i could not figure out how to do the OR logic and i was getting overwrites on each subsequent hit.

EDIT: as for the exit requirement, i want the code to stop if the risky_events is blank, but i think i can figure that out with some more reading of documentation :) 

thanks again!

Comment: Please go ahead and accept/upvote the answer if it indeed worked for you, so people know where to look for a resolution :)